# using WP7 Panorama with views based if a user is logged in or not

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am hoping someone can point me in the right direction. I want to create a wp7 panorama type applicaton.

The applicaton requires the user to be logged in for the user to be able to work with a group of panorma items.

So I start creating a Panorama application deleting the MainPage.xaml file and create a new panorama page in my Views folder called MainDetailsView. I have updated the VMAppManifest file to point to the new view.

What is the best way to create a login view that fits into the panorama styled application. Do Ijust create all of the panormaitems I want within MainDetailsView, binding the visibility of each of the  PanoramaItems to a converter. If the user is logged in then set the visibilty to true else set it to false?

How then does this fit using the mvvm pattern?

Answer (score 0):

Your login UI could be embedded within a [Popup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) that you show on top of the panorama when required.

Also, Peter Torr has a couple of posts on [how to exit a Windows Phone application](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ptorr/archive/2010/08/01/exiting-a-windows-phone-application.aspx) and [how to redirect an initial navigation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ptorr/archive/2010/08/28/redirecting-an-initial-navigation.aspx) that touch on that scenario.